# Ruby using prepend to patch a class doesn't work

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, prepend

I'm trying to patch the verb methods in sinatra to add an extra function call before it. I was having problems in using an alias chain to keep the original methods, but I discovered that prepend would allow me to do what I want without using such a hacky method.

However my prepended functions are not being called and are simply being ignored. 
what's going on?

Here's my patch:

```
if defined? Sinatra::Base   
    module Restman
        module Patches
            module Sinatra_Base_Patch           
                [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :head, :options, :patch, :link, :unlink].each do |func_name|
                    define_method func_name do |*args,&block|
                        if args.first.class == Symbol
                            super(Restman::Routes.get(args.first)[:uri],*block)
                        else
                            super(*args,*block)
                        end

                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    ::Sinatra::Base.prepend Restman::Patches::Sinatra_Base_Patch
end
```

EDIT:(explanation)

The patch is pretty simple, it overrides sinatra's normal HTTP verb methods and checks if a symbol was passed to it or not, if one was then it passes the symbol to a method that returns a mapping and takes the url out of the mapping and then passes that up to sinatra's normal HTTP verb methods.

This is so I can have:

```
Restman::Routes.define do
  map :root, to: '/'
end
```

and then do

```
get :root do
 'hello world!'
end
```

I thinking of trying refinements, that might work better.. maybe?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a way that doesn't require us writing a Sinatra web app just to debug your code? I don't even have Sinatra installed at the moment. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: are you sure that the monkeypatch is applied properly? add some puts-statements to find out whats going on

Comment: I don't know to be honest, prepend is supposed to allow me to monkey patch without directly opening the original class, I followed the example but it's not working like I expect it to (see op edit for what this patch does). I did try using put's but the function doesn't get called at all so nothing get's outputted. Oddly though, the other class patching using `prepend` I did worked; I know it did since a class I have uses a patched class method and it doesn't throw a hissy fit saying that the method doesn't exist (which it would if the patching failed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get`, `post`, `put` etc. methods in Sinatra are *class methods*, but you are creating *instance* methods with those names. In order to intercept the methods you need to prepend the `Sinatra::Base` singleton class.

Try this:

```
::Sinatra::Base.singleton_class.prepend Restman::Patches::Sinatra_Base_Patch
```

Comment: I've tried using `define_singleton_method` to no effect but I'll try this as well tommrow.

Comment: This worked, I don't know why `define_singleton_method` didn't but I don't care, `singleton_class.prepend` worked and that's good enough for me!